# Changing images with a button

Tags: javascript, python

I would like to know how to change between 4 images in JavaScript. I have come from Python, and I would like to find a short solution. I'm using code that would be used in Python, but I want a JavaScript code with the same principle. Made and array, and when the button is clicked, if it is on one, display the next image in the array.

This is the structure so far:

```
<script>   
    var images = ["i1.gif","i2.gif","i3.gif","i4.gif"]
    position=0;

    function changeImage() {
        for position in range(4):
            if position==4:
                position=0
            print(images[position])
    }
</script>
```

This is the command called when the button is clicked, but I'm not sure not to trigger it. Any help with an explanation will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a JavaScript code derived from yours:

```
var images = [ "i1.gif", "i2.gif", "i3.gif", "i4.gif" ];
var position = 0;

function changeImage() {
    position = position + 1;  // or position++; or position += 1;

    // Array indexes are counted starting from 0.
    // That means 'position' can only go up to 3
    // in a length 4 array.
    if (position >= images.length) {
        position = 0;
    }

    // This doesn't actually display the images,
    // it just prints out their names.
    console.log(images[position]);
}
```

I removed the for loop because it would run from start to finish, and would only ever return you the last image of the array. Also, as I commented on the code, a `print` (or in this case, `console.log`) won't actually display the image, it will just return its name (`"i1.gif"`, `"i2.gif"`, etc).

Answer (score 0):

First off, there is no equivalent for Python's ranges in JavaScript as far as I know of. Instead, you can iterate over the image array. The idea is the same as

```py
for x in array:
  do_something(x)
```

The thing is... This is a *little bit* more cumbersome in JavaScript than in Python.

You see, in JavaScript arrays are actually *objects*. But a JavaScript object isn't the same as a Python object. JavaScript objects are actually quite similar to Python *dictionaries*. They store a key-value pair association. An array is just an object whose keys are `0, 1, 2...`. It also has a few magical fields so that the JavaScript VM knows how to treat it efficiently.

Now, why is this important? Well, the thing is that, in a quite bad (in my opinion) design decision, instead of the `for ... in` operator in JavaScript working the same as in Python, it actually iterates over object *keys*, and not object *values*!

So you actually need to do this to iterate over an object's values:

```
for(var x in array) {
  do_something(array[x]);
}
```

So a complete solution for what you are trying to do would be:

```
var images = [ "i1.gif", "i2.gif", "i3.gif", "i4.gif" ];
var position = 0;

function changeImage() {
  for(var position in images) {
    console.log(images[position]);
  }
}
```

Now, this will obviously only print the name of each image, but by replacing `console.log` with any other function you can iterate over your images doing anything with them.

The whole `for ... in` loop is a bit cumbersome to use, so ES6 (the latest stable revision of JavaScript) added the `for ... of` loop, which works exactly like Python's `for ... in`. For example, you could rewrite the `changeImage()` function as:

```
function changeImage() { 
  for(const img of images) {
    console.log(img);
  }
}
```

But you seem to be trying to make this work in a browser, and [getting ES6 to work consistently in a browser requires compiling](https://babeljs.io/), so I would stick to `for ... in` loops for now, even if they are more annoying to work with.

Good luck!

EDIT: Right after finishing answering, I remembered one other thing:

In JavaScript, the `for ... in` loop is *not guaranteed* to go over the array keys *in key order*. So if processing the images in a specific order is important to you, you should instead use:

```
function changeImages() {
  images.forEach(function(image) {
    console.log(image);
  }
}
```

This uses the [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method, which *is* guaranteed to traverse array keys in numeric order.